# Hibernate second level cacheing - Program does not terminate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, second-level-cache

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_details")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY) 
public class UserDetails {...}
```

The above code is how I defined my Entity class, UserDetails,  as `cacheable`. I also added two lines in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` :

```
    <!-- second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
```

In my service main method I am accessing twice the same UserDetails Object, in different sessions :

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
user = (UserDetails)session.get(UserDetails.class, 3);
logger.info(user);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();

Session session2 = sessionFactory.openSession();
session2.beginTransaction();
UserDetails user2 = new UserDetails();
user2 = (UserDetails)session2.get(UserDetails.class, 3);
logger.info(user2);
session2.getTransaction().commit();
session2.close();
```

I get, as expected only one `SELECT` query, which implies that hibernate fetches the data from the second level cache. I also print fine my objects on the console.

But, my program does not end. It sits there running, on `Eclipse`, and I have to stop it manually. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong is that you don't shut down the `SessionFactory`, which maintains a lot of system resources. Some of those resources must be threads, which keep your application from ending.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the version of ehcache. I have tried this thing and it worked. See this
http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/6450.page